# What is the meaning of >: Null <: in Scala?

Tags: scala

I searched a lot, but I didn't find anything, What is the meaning of this type of `type declaration` in Scala?

```
type Ident >: Null <: AnyRef
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Keyword `type` is for type alias declaration, just like `val` and `def` are for value and method declaration. In this case it's an abstract type alias with constraints, so it's a type member of some `trait` or `class` - type alias in local scope can't be abstract and can't have constraints.

Type `Ident` is a subtype of `AnyRef` and supertype of `Null`.

**AnyRef**

[`AnyRef`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.AnyRef) is an ancestor of all reference types, all types except `Int`, `Long`, `Char` and so on (Java primitives).

**Null**

[`Null`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Null) is subtype of all "nullable" types. In fact it's a subtype of all reference types.

Since all `AnyRef` are nullable the only additional constraint from `>: Null` is that `Ident` is not `Nothing`.

See [Scala’s type hierarchy](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596155957/ScalaObjectSystem.html):

[image: Scala’s type hierarchy]

Comment: A quick follow-up question then ('cause I'm curious), isn't the lower bound here superfluous? Since the `Null` is subtype of all reference types and the type already has the upper-bound defined as *any reference type*?

Comment: Thanks, I know the hierarchy, but my question was what means this command

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek: I guess so. But `Null` type could be mentioned as explicit warning that value could be `null`.

Comment: @Pooya thats not a command but a simple constraint which says to Scalac that values of this type has Null as its subtype

Comment: @AlexIv So is it means that you can set Null to the declared values with this type?

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek: with `>: Null` `Ident` can't be `Nothing`.

Comment: @senia Right, now I can see that. I wonder what practical implications that entails...

Comment: @Pooya: You can use `null` as value of any reference type (`AnyRef`): `null: String`. `>: Null` here means that `Ident` can't be `Nothing`.

Comment: @Pooya Such boundaries are used in (contra/co)variance, for constraining you values with specified type, i've updated my answer with a little example

Answer (score 7):

To add to @senia's answer: this isn't a *type* declaration, this is an *abstract type member* declaration, found in context like

```
trait Foo { // or perhaps class
  type Ident >: Null <: AnyRef
}
```

and means that any concrete implementation of `Foo` must define some type to be `Ident`, and this type has to satisfy constraints described in @senia's answer.

Comment: Yes, this type definition was in a trait

Answer (score 1):

In your case `Null` is a subtype of `Ident` and `AnyRef` is its supertype. In without this boundaries common subtype of all type is `Nothing`, but you specify it to be `Null`, with is a subtype of all object when Nothing is a subtype of everything (including Int, Long, etc..)

Things like Null and Nothing are used in Type System, basically in type (Contra/Co)variance. Example:

```
sealed trait Container[+A >: Null <: AnyRef]
case class Full[A >: Null <: AnyRef](value: A) extends Container[A]
case object Empty extends Container[Null]
```

This compiles fine:

```
val c: Container[String] = Full("String")
val e: Container[String] = Empty
```

But this fails, because our lower bound is Null and upper is AnyRef:

```
val ff: Container[Int] = Full(10)
val f: Container[Int] = Empty
```

We can't put `Int` here beacuse this type violates out contraints