# Type matching on generic Scala trait

Tags: scala

I am just dipping my toes into generics and am wondering if there is a better way to achieve the following:

I have a sealed trait that has an abstract name and an overridden equals(). I want the overridden equals to match on both type and name. Below is what I have.

```
sealed trait NamedCampaign[A <: NamedCampaign] {
  def name: String

  override def equals(obj: Any): Boolean = obj match {
    case x: A => x.name == this.name
    case _ => false
  }
}

case class AdCampaign(name: String, objective: String, status: String, buyingType: String) extends NamedCampaign[AdCampaign]
case class AdSet(name: String, status: String, dailyBudget: Int, lifetimeBudget: Int, startTime: Int, endTime: Int, campaign: String) extends NamedCampaign[AdSet]
```

In layman's terms, I want two objects to be considered equal if they are the same class and have the same name. Is there a better/faster/more idiomatic way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have can't work because of erasure. The type `A` isn't known at runtime.

Adapted from [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24198735/scala-generic-array-inside-trait/24200071#24200071):

```
sealed trait NamedCampaign[A <: NamedCampaign] {
  implicit def classTagA: ClassTag[A]
  def name: String
  override def equals(obj: Any): Boolean = obj match {
    case classTagA(x) => x.name == this.name
    case _ => false
  }
}

case class AdCampaign(name: String, objective: String, status: String,
  buyingType: String)(implicit val classTagA: ClassTag[AdCampaign])
  extends NamedCampaign[AdCampaign]

case class AdSet(name: String, status: String, dailyBudget: Int,
  lifetimeBudget: Int, startTime: Int, endTime: Int, campaign: String)
  (implicit val classTagA: ClassTag[AdSet]) extends NamedCampaign[AdSet]
```

---

A better way to write this is with a [canEqual](http://marcus-christie.blogspot.com/2014/03/scala-object-equality-and-canequal.html) method.

```
sealed trait NamedCampaign {
  def name: String
  def canEqual(that: Any): Boolean
  override def equals(other: Any): Boolean = other match {
    case that: NamedCampaign => (that canEqual this) &&
                                (this.name == that.name)
    case _ => false
  }
}

case class AdCampaign(name: String, objective: String, status: String,
    buyingType: String) extends NamedCampaign {
  override def canEqual(that: Any) = that.isInstanceOf[AdCampaign]
}

case class AdSet(name: String, status: String, dailyBudget: Int,
    lifetimeBudget: Int, startTime: Int, endTime: Int, campaign: String)
    extends NamedCampaign {
  override def canEqual(that: Any) = that.isInstanceOf[AdSet]
}
```

---

My two cents: I don't think it's ever appropriate to override `equals` on a case class. You'll regret it the moment you ever want to compare all of the fields (which you're likely to want to do in, say, a unit test).

Comment: Hmmmm, that seems more complex than just writing out the equals method by hand for both case classes. Being as there will only probably be one more case class, can you see any benefit of using type reflection and a mixed in trait?