# Initial array elements in Scala?

Tags: arrays, scala

```
class testing[T <: IntStorage : ClassTag] {
  var the_array = Array.ofDim[T](10, 10)
}
```

I wonder what "the_array" contains before putting any element in it if T is an abstract class? So what are the initial elements of the array?

And what if the array can also contain empty elements, None for example. How could I first initialize the array with all "empty", i.e. None, cells and then fill certain rows and columns?

Comment: `None` is **not** "empty". It is a stand-alone `object` and part of `Option[X]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scala, for all of the things it does right, unfortunately still harbors the worst criminal from the Java realm: the dreaded `null` value, often called the billion dollar mistake.

In Scala, every `AnyRef` value (roughly speaking, anything that would be non-primitive in Java) can be `null`. It's not idiomatic to do this, and any seasoned Scala dev will avoid `null` like the plague. But it's there, like a specter, waiting to leap up and bite unsuspecting programmers in the night.

`Array.ofDim` returns default-initialized values. For `AnyVal`, this means their "zero" value, so `Array.ofDim[Int]` returns an array of zeroes. For `AnyRef`, this returns an array of `null`.

```
scala> var x = Array.ofDim[A](10) // Assuming A is some class
var x: Array[A] = Array(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null)
```

Ideally, you'll want to fill the array with something sensible immediately. Or, even better, use the [`Array.fill`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/3.0.2/scala/Array$.html#fill-fffff6a8) method, which works the exact same way but allows you to immediately initialize the array values.

Note that Scala 3 has an opt-in compiler option called `-Yexplicit-nulls`, which explicitly marks any value that can potentially be `null` and makes it explicit in the type system. Unfortunately, it seems that `Array.ofDim` still returns an `Array[T]` even in this mode, effectively making its type a lie in Scala 3's new null checker. I conclude that `ofDim` is likely intended as a "low-level" primitive for allocating empty arrays, and that `fill` should probably be used instead in most cases, in the same way that `asInstanceOf` is a low-level primitive which should be avoided in favor of pattern matching (or simply avoiding downcasting altogether, ideally).

Comment: I would also point out that `tabulate` is also very useful. - On top of that, it is worth pointing that `Array` is also another carry over from **Java** and proper collections should be preferred.

Comment: Just a nitpick: "every AnyRef value can be null" is mostly true, but not exactly, which is why you need to write things like `Ident >: Null <: AnyRef` when you want to handle nullable values in your generics (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18054614/what-is-the-meaning-of-null-in-scala)